# django custom registration view, redirect fail

Tags: python, django, http-redirect, django-registration

I am using Django-registration and I have subclassed the BaseRegistrationView to customised a backend.

However, the HttpResponseRedirect fail to redirect to a new page when the condition is met.

The code is listed below:

```
class CustomRegistrationView(BaseRegistrationView):
  def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):
    captchaMatch = False

    #check captcha
    captchaValue = request.session.get('captcha')
    captchaValueSubmitted = cleaned_data['captcha'] + "123"

    if captchaValue != captchaValueSubmitted:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('InvitationRequired'))
    else:
        self.captchaMatch = True

    username, email, password = cleaned_data['username'], cleaned_data['email'], cleaned_data['password1']
    if Site._meta.installed:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
    else:
        site = RequestSite(request)
    new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                                password, site)


    signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                 user=new_user,
                                 request=request)
    return new_user

def registration_allowed(self, request):
    """
    Indicate whether account registration is currently permitted,
    based on the value of the setting ``REGISTRATION_OPEN``. This
    is determined as follows:

    * If ``REGISTRATION_OPEN`` is not specified in settings, or is
      set to ``True``, registration is permitted.

    * If ``REGISTRATION_OPEN`` is both specified and set to
      ``False``, registration is not permitted.

    """
    return getattr(settings, 'REGISTRATION_OPEN', True)

def get_success_url(self, request, user):
    """
    Return the name of the URL to redirect to after successful
    user registration.

    """
    print "get successful url"
    if self.captchaMatch:
        return ('registration_complete', (), {})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('InvitationRequired'))
```

Can anyone help explain why the redirection is executed inside the function **register** ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `register` method is supposed to return a user or `None`. Not an `HttpRedirect` object. Since I'm not familiar with this specific app, try to see how they handle failure on the original method and follow that policy (e.b. return `None` or raise an `Exception`).

Also, based on the comments on the `get_success_url()` method, I would expect the code to be like this:

```
def get_success_url(self, request, user):
  """
  Return the name of the URL to redirect to after successful
  user registration.
  """
  if self.captchaMatch:
     return ('registration_complete', (), {})
  else:
     return ('InvitationRequired', (), {})
```

I guess you should not return a `HttpResponse` instance, as the method is used to get the URL to be redirect to (not the redirection itself).